# How to add some parameter to post parameter when listener add in icecast url authentication

Tags: icecast

Icecast send action,mount,server and so on information to listener_joined.php when listener add. I want icecast to send other information.

> Note: The mount here (unlike the start/end options) states the requested url including any query parameters, so for instance the requested URL can be /stream.ogg&session=xyz, but note that each option data is escaped before being passed via POST.

I read this. So I try to get

> "/example.ogg&session=xyz"

But I get

> "404 - The file you requested could not be found"

My icecast config is this.

```
<mount>
    <mount-name>/example.ogg</mount-name>
    <authentication type="url">             
        <option name="listener_add" value="http://localhost/listener_joined.php"/>
        <option name="listener_remove" value="http://localhost/listener_left.php"/>
        <option name="username" value="user"/>
        <option name="password" value="pass"/>
        <option name="auth_header" value="icecast-auth-user: 1"/>
    </authentication>
</mount>
```

How to add some parameter to post parameter when listener add in icecast url authentication?

Comment: Is there even a stream running on /example.ogg? Authentication code is only called if there is something to authenticate, not on a failure.

Comment: also you said you requested /stream.ogg while the config is for /example.ogg

Comment: /example.ogg is running now.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong. I requested /example.ogg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper URL query parameter separator as specified in the [HTTP 1.0 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#page-14) is the question mark "?".
So your URL part should be: `/example.ogg?session=xyz` and not `/example.ogg&session=xyz`. The latter would be interpreted as a whole path and as it doesn't exist a 404 is appropriate.

Comment: I tried your solution. But Icecast didn't sent session.

Comment: It does. I'd recommend to dump the whole request or even look at it using e.g. Wireshark. You are likely overlooking that the query part is escaped and can not be used directly, but needs to be decoded (also for security reasons).